# matmult sign in R-help file of package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write the help file of an R package and everything after '%*%' in

```
a1%*%M
```

gets ignored. Anybody knows how to remediate?

Comment: You're editing `.Rd` files manually? or are you using something like `roxygen2`?

Comment: no i'm not using roxygen2....i'm editing them manually.

Comment: Are you starting a new R session to check this? I am unable to replicate this - and I've been updating and installing a development version of one of my packages more than daily for the past week so I would have seen this. What version of R are you using?

Comment: R. And Im under ubuntu. I'm starting a new R session. I'm using 3.0.1. I've also checked the .Rd files in the .tar.gz and they are the new version. Yet, when I install the package through install.packages("packagename.tar.gz",source=NULL) in R (but I've also tried R CMD install) I still get the old versions. Is there an option to make sure it updates the manual?

Comment: bump the version number, install, start R, then try `packageVersion("packagename")` to make sure you're loading the new version of the package.

Comment: I think I got it. It seems, in the example in the R package, everything after and including the '%*%' is taken as a comment. Is this possible? (the only difference between the two version of the help files are in a example where I multiply the answer by something else.)

Comment: Can you edit your question so it reflects your real question?  or else @GSee's comment above should be the answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Parsing Rd Files](http://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf)

> An unescaped percent symbol % marks the beginning of an Rd comment, which runs to the end of the current line. The parser returns
>   these marked as COMMENT tokens.

Your `examples` section needs to escape those `%` symbols.  Something like this:

```
\examples{
letters[1:10] \%in\% letters[1:3]
}
```